# Utility for finding arbitrary values in arbitrary containers

Tags: c++, c++14

What do you think?

```
#include <algorithm>

#include <type_traits>

namespace
{

template <typename C, typename = std::size_t>
struct has_find: std::false_type
{
};

template <typename C>
struct has_find<C,
  decltype(
    sizeof(
      (typename C::iterator(C::*)(
        typename C::key_type const&))(&C::find)
    ) |
    sizeof(
      (typename C::const_iterator(C::*)(
        typename C::key_type const&) const)(&C::find)
    )
  )
> : std::true_type
{
};

}

template <class Container, class Key, typename F>
inline std::enable_if_t<!has_find<Container>{}>
find(Container& c, Key const& k, F&& f) noexcept
{
  f(std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), k));
}

template <class Container, class Key, typename F>
inline std::enable_if_t<has_find<Container>{}>
find(Container& c, Key const& k, F&& f) noexcept
{
  f(c.find(k));
}
```

Usage:

```
find(container, key, [&](auto const i){ std::cout << "found it" << std::endl; });
```

Comment: So you decided to re-write `std::find_if()`

Comment: @LokiAstari I don't think find_if works on std::map and it's not exactly find_if either.

Comment: `find_if()` works on any container that supports iterators (which is all containers).

Comment: @LokiAstari well, it's not exactly the same lol :) The predicate will be called for each element in that case, for one thing.

Comment: OK. I see that now. It should be called `find_first_and_execute()` or if you were me `findFirstAndExecute()`

Comment: @LokiAstari but it's a really long name, which could be a basis for criticism itself.

Comment: Long name a bias for criticism. If it conveyed no meaning. But one of the big things is to have self documenting code. A function name should describe what it does so I don't need to look it up. Go read about "Self Documenting Code"

Comment: @LokiAstari Better "process" than "execute", as the found one isn't the callable.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 4 → 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace
{
    /* implementation details */
}
```

Do you really need the level of protection an anonymous namespace provides?  Prefer using a named namespace (`private`, `detail`, etc) to protect against accidental usage.  Use anonymous namespaces for details that need to be limited to the local translation unit.

---

```
  template <class Container, class Key, typename F>
  inline std::enable_if_t<!has_find<Container>{}>
  find(Container& c, Key const& k, F&& f) noexcept
  {
    f(std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), k));
  }
```

When programming generically, prefer calling the non-member functions.  Member `begin` and `end` do not exist for all containers.  However, the standard containers and [c](/questions/tagged/c) arrays are supported by non-member `begin`, `end`, and the const/reverse variants.

How does the `noexcept` specification work if `f()` can throw?

It's not clear why you are applying a function to a `find` result.  Consider writing a wrapper (`find_and_apply`) on a generic non-member `find` to apply the result to a function.

Using Expression SFINAE (ymmv on MSVC support), you can simply check if the expression `c.find(key)` is a well-formed expression.  If the expression is ill-formed, the overloaded function is culled from the overload set.

```
namespace detail {
  template <class Container, class Key>
  auto find(Container& c, const Key& key, int) -> decltype(c.find(key)) {
    return c.find(key);
  }

  using std::begin; // adl
  using std::end;

  template <class Container, class Key>
  auto find(Container& c, const Key& key, char) -> decltype(begin(c)) {
    return std::find(begin(c), end(c), key);
  }
}

template <class Container, class Key>
auto find(Container& c, const Key& key) -> decltype(detail::find(c, key, 0)) {
  return detail::find(c, key, 0);
}
```

*Note:* The third parameter in the detail functions utilizes integral types for priority tag dispatching.

Comment: This is good advice that expands on the original idea. I didn't envision supporting arrays :)

Answer (score 4):

From the first glance I see 2 problems:

**Item1**. This code fails to compile with the highest warning level

```
src/test.cpp:21:47: error: use of old-style cast [-Werror=old-style-cast]
         typename C::key_type const&))(&C::find)
                                               ^
src/test.cpp:25:53: error: use of old-style cast [-Werror=old-style-cast]
         typename C::key_type const&) const)(&C::find)
```

**Item2**. Even if element is not found - predicate is called with end() iterator. Maybe it is better not to change the find interface and just allow to call container find when available and std::find otherwise?

Comment: but that's the whole idea, you can see if key is found by checking the iterator. Usually you want to know, if it is not found, as that is always possible.

Comment: @user1095108: The point is you are calling `f()` on the `end()` iterator. Which is one **past** the end. So there is no data element. That is why the find interface returns an iterator to see if you actually found something you need to compare against `end()`. Its also why you are getting compiler errors.

Comment: @LokiAstari it's usually a warning, he just set the compiler to the highest warning level.

Comment: @user1095108: A warning is a logical error in the code. You should always compile with the warnings turned up and the warnings treated as errors. Sorry. To a beginner warning sounds like its not important. But it just means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @LokiAstari There are such things as false warnings. But they are reasonably rare, and nearly always there's a way to clarify the code and thus avoid the warning.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I disagree. A compiler warning just mean you made an assumption and the compiler is doing work you should have done. Assumptions are never portable. Get rid of the warning. Example above.  "old style cast" seems perfectly harmless. But its not. You are throwing away type information which may actually be hiding a real error. You should be using the more controlled C++ casts which allow you to define at a finer grain what type information you are throwing (some is harmless but most are not).

Comment: @LokiAstari I get many warnings compiling well-known libraries, like cairo, pixman, ... Working around a warning is a good idea, I just used -Wall and -Wextra and assumed those were sufficient.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Some c-style-casts have no analogue in a chain of xxx_casts. Thus, I disagree.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Such as. All C casts can be represented by a set of C++ casts. That's why there are four of them for the different things they do. If you are doing something that needs more you are off in UB and thus in danger and thus need an error.

Comment: I replaced the C style cast with a static_cast, but I disagree my old code was flawed, as the fix is merely aesthetic. The original code was not ill-formed IMO.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Try casting from / to inaccessible unambiguous base. That's well-defined, though quite rude.

Comment: @user1095108: Its not about being ill-formed. Its about documentation. Did you replace it with `reinterpret_cast<>()` then I need to look harder at it. Did you replace it with `static_cast<>()` or `dynamic_cast<>()` then I can just breeze over it, did you replace it with `const_cast<>()` then I would reject your code and send you back to re-write it. Old style C casts hide a lot of horrible stuff. The C++ casts force you to think about the correct type of cast and thus implicitly document it (with the name of the cast).

Comment: @LokiAstari lol :) I did comment, it was a static_cast, but really :)

Comment: @user1095108: My view of warnings is like this - If you are writing a HelloWorld sample which nobody will see but you - you can even disable warnings at all. If you are writing utility class/function you expect to be used by others I'm looking at it as if I'm going to include it somewhere in my 1000+ source code files project. And if this h-file will be included in only 100 cpp file - you'll give me 200 warnings in my build output. If you think I'll thank you for this - think again. Since so many warnings will make me skip 1 or 2 warnings that really matter.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky However, if the warning is not picked up by -Wall and -Wextra, you might think twice about being so strict?

Comment: @user1095108 - since you are not my team leader - you cannot decide what is the best warning level for my project. I mean - you have no control over the environment where you code will be compiled - if you want to make it open source.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your `has_find` is far too over-specified.
Take a look at the [docs for `std::map.find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), and you will find support for other key-types.

Also you should avoid using c-style-casts, as they are far too versatile and thus fail to make your intent manifest.

```
// From C++17:
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

template <class T, class K, class = void>
struct has_find : std::false_type {};
template <class T, class K, class U = void_t<decltype(
    std::declval<typename T::const_iterator&>() = std::declval<T&>().find(std::declval<K&>())
)>>
struct has_find<T, K, U> : std::true_type {};
```

Next, your `find()`'s contract and prototype are surprising. Nobody expects it to call the supplied callable with the result of trying to find the element.

If you decide to do so anyway, call it something more like `find_and_process()`, and don't execute the callback with an end-iterator.

Comment: The idea was to avoid having to write code initializing a temporary variable like `auto const i(map.find("blabla"))` then checking for end() and then doing something with `i`, if key was or wasn't found.

Comment: Well, iterators are generally cheaply, if not trivially, copyable. So, don't worry about that.

Comment: I wasn't worried, just the boilerplate code bothered me.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion - use convenience functions for common operations.

```
template<class Container, class Key>
bool exists(Container const& container, Key const& key)
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    find(container, key, [&](auto const i)
    {
        returnValue = (i != end(container));
    });

    return returnValue;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> container = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int key = 7;

    // Ah, less typing
    if (exists(container, key))
        std::cout << "found it" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;

    // Than this lambda stuff
    find(container, key, [&](auto const i)
    {
        if (i != container.end())
            std::cout << "found it" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
    });
}
```

And for mutating the value, maybe something like...

```
ValueType* lookup(Container& container, Key const& key);

...

if (auto v = lookup(container, key))
    *v = 12;
```

Comment: nice try mercury, but you need to practice writing c++ hieroglyphics some more :)

Answer (score 0):

I went with this. It supports arrays, maps and vectors. Changed the name and added the appropriate noexcepts.

```
namespace detail
{

template <class Container, class Key>
inline auto find(Container& c, Key const& k, int)
  noexcept(noexcept(c.find(k))) -> decltype(c.find(k))
{
  return c.find(k);
}

template <class Container, class Key>
inline auto find(Container& c, Key const& k, char)
  noexcept(noexcept(std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), k))) ->
  decltype(std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), k))
{
  return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), k);
}

}

template <class Container, class Key>
inline auto any_find(Container& c, Key const& k) noexcept(
  noexcept(detail::find(c, k, 0))
)
{
  return detail::find(c, k, 0);
}

template <class Container, class Key, typename F>
inline void any_find(Container& c, Key const& k, F&& f) noexcept(
  noexcept(f(detail::find(c, k, 0)))
)
{
  f(detail::find(c, k, 0));
}
```